# Rails What is the best way to generate a json form a large amout of data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api

I am working on a project that is a backend for a mobile app.

Una of the API calls returns a large amount of data as a json and it takes a lot to genrate the json.

Right now, I am pre processing the data to generate a hash with all the information and the

```
Places.each do |item|

      place = item.place

      place.discounts.each do |discount|
        response_item = {
            :id => place.id,
            :latitude => item.latitude,
            :longitude => item.longitude,
            :name => place.name,
            :url_image => place.img,
            :stars => 0,
            :is_habitue => false,#is_habitue,
            :discount => {
                :id => discount.id,
                :title => discount.title,
                :description => discount.description,
                :raw_title => discount.raw_title,
                :expiration => discount.expiration
            }
        }

        categories = []
        place.categories.each do |category|
          categories.append ({
              :name => category.name,
              :label => category.label
          })
        end
        response_item[:categories] = categories

        benefits = []
        discount.benefits.each do |benefit|
          benefits.append ({
            :benefit_type => benefit.benefit_type,
            :label => benefit.label
          })
        end
        response_item[:benefits] = benefits

        processed_places.append response_item
      end
end
render :json => {:places=>processed_places}, :status=>200
```

I takes about 1.4 seconds to process 2700 results but more than 6 seconds to generate the json.

thanks

Comment: How are you processing the JSON? More code would be great.

Comment: @KieranAndrews I've updated the question. I added how I generate the hash that later render as json

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try RABL. It's got great features :)